# If one can choose to fwrite() 100 1 bytes, or 1 100 bytes, which approach should be prefered?

Tags: c

I am interested if there is a theoretical speed difference between

```
fwrite(str , 1 , 100 , fp );
```

and

```
fwrite(str , 100 , 1 , fp );
```

based on how the function is written in glibc, and how many write calls it makes and how it is buffered (disregarding hardware differences on gcc).

Comment: The `fwrite` function is defined to write "from the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements whose size is specified by size". So, from a coding style perspective, your code should state *the truth*. If you're writing 100 integers of `sizeof(int) == 4`, your nmemb should be 100 and your size should be 4. If you're writing 400 `char`, your nmemb should be 400 and your size should be 1. Trying to "optimize" at this level is usually a waste of time and reduces readability of your source. (And, as the answer shows, doesn't actually do anything anyway.)

Comment: Have you looked at the code for fwrite? eg: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iofwrite.c . There's essentially no speed difference between 1, 100 and 100, 1 because the two are multiplied together in the source code to get the number of bytes to write.

Comment: Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350785/performance-of-fwrite-and-write-size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference for [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/fwrite.c?id=a08910fc2cc739f631b75b2d09b8d72a0d64d285) or [glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/e2756903329365134089d23548e9083d23bc3dd9/libio/iofwrite.c#L30-L39), or the [FreeBSD libc](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/b8da3b62a57464d7be1b95b1bdae83f592209f74/lib/libc/stdio/fwrite.c#L81-L94) since they all call an underlying function with `size*nmemb`:

### musl

```
size_t fwrite(const void *restrict src, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *restrict f)
{
    size_t k, l = size*nmemb;
    // ...
    k = __fwritex(src, l, f);
```

### glibc

```
size_t
_IO_fwrite (const void *buf, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *fp)
{
  size_t request = size * count;
  // ...
  written = _IO_sputn (fp, (const char *) buf, request);
```

### freebsd

```
    n = count * size;
    // ...
    uio.uio_resid = iov.iov_len = n;
    // ...
    if (__sfvwrite(fp, &uio) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote 2 pieces of code to examine the difference between their performance.

`a.c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {

        char* str = "Hello\n";
        FILE* fd = fopen("out.txt", "w");
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
                fwrite(str , 1 , 100 , fd);

        fclose(fd);
        return 0;

}
```

`b.c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {

        char* str = "Hello\n";
        FILE* fd = fopen("out.txt", "w");
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
                fwrite(str , 100 , 1 , fd);
        fclose(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```bash
(a.riahi@asax.local@U-Riahi:cplay) > gcc a.c
(a.riahi@asax.local@U-Riahi:cplay) > time ./a.out 

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
(a.riahi@asax.local@U-Riahi:cplay) > gcc b.c
(a.riahi@asax.local@U-Riahi:cplay) > time ./a.out 

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
```

There no real difference between them.

Comment: these minimal differences happen accidentially (e.g.: the 'faster' version uses more sys time). Btw.: writing 100 bytes starting with `str` causes UB as it points to a string literal of only only 6 bytes including `'\0`' and you call `fopen()` 1000 times without closing it.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thanks for mentioning it. It edited the answer.

Comment: When posting a benchmark, it would be useful to specify on which platform (e.g. compiler, library and operating system) you performed the benchmark.